# Some Basic Questions about Make: Compiling a Report with Figures

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to get Make working for recompiling reports every time a figure gets updated. I have the following code:

```
fig1.eps : images/code/fig1.m
        matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r 'run ./images/code/fig1.m'
```

1. How do I match on all figures -- like fig*.eps. I want to check all figures and update those that are not up to date.
2. When I run the command above, it continually reruns. This is to say: fig1.eps is generated. After I run make again, it should give me a message "fig1.eps is up to date." But it doesn't, the script reruns. Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How do I match on all figures -- like fig*.eps. I want to check all figures and update those that are not up to date.

If you are using GNU's implementation of `make`, then you can use a pattern rule:

```
fig%.eps : images/code/fig%.m
        matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r 'run ./$<'
```

If you are using another version of `make` then the best you can do without writing a separate rule for each figure is probably to write a suffix rule, which will generate files in the same directory as the corresponding Matlab script, something like:

```
.m.eps :
        matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r 'run ./$<'

.SUFFIXES: .m .eps
```

Either of these options, however, requires you to somewhere specify all the figures to be created.  At its simplest, you would just enumerate:

```
FIGS = fig1.eps fig2.eps fig5a.eps fig17.1.eps
```

... and specify the figures as prerequisites for the default (or some other) target:

```
all: $(FIGS)
```

With GNU `make`, however, if your Matlab files are arranged and named conducively then you could also use wildcard expansion or a shell command to obtain the result:

```
FIGS = $(shell cd images/code && ls fig*.m | sed 's/\.m$$/.eps')
```

> 2. When I run the command above, it continually reruns. This is to say: fig1.eps is generated. After I run make again, it should give me
>      a message "fig1.eps is up to date." But it doesn't, the script reruns.
>      Why is it doing this?

Very likely because your matlab command is not producing the target of the rule.  For example, maybe it is creating a file of the same name, but in a different directory, or maybe it is not writing its output to a file at all.  Possibly because some other rule is also being triggered that causes the `.eps` file to be removed.